# How do the Wagnerian antecedents of 'total art' appear in modernism, and does it have anything to do with arts and crafts?

Tags: modernism

How do the Wagnerian antecedents of 'total art' appear in modernism, and does it have anything to do with arts and crafts? I'm just interested in that narrative today.